# column reference "col_1" is ambiguous plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm writing postgresql function which inserts data and returns successfully inserted data rows.

The code is below.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fn_insert_test(json_data jsonb)
 returns  table(col_1 varchar(255),
                col_2 varchar(255),
                col_3 timestamp)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
declare
    --
begin
    with my_table as (
       with my_table1(my_json) as (
            values(
            json_data
            )
         )
        insert into "test"(col_1, col_2, col_3)
        select
            elem->>'val1', elem->>'val2', now()
        from
            my_table1 t, jsonb_array_elements(my_json->'_data') elem
        on conflict(col_1) do nothing
        returning *
    )
    select * from my_table;
end
$function$
;

select fn_insert_test('{"_data": [{"val1":"1", "val2":"1"}, {"val1":"2", "val2":"2"}]}');
```

It occurs error below.

```
SQL Error [42702]: ERROR: column reference "col_1" is ambiguous
  Detail: It could refer to either a PL/pgSQL variable or a table column.
  Where: PL/pgSQL function fn_insert_test(jsonb) line 5 at SQL statement
```

[edit]

[image: data in test table]

[image: properties of test table]

[image: constraints of test table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the real problem here. There is a lot of problems in your code : 
-> If you want to return a table, you have to use 'return query' : http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/plpgsql-function-returns-a-table/
-> I do not think you can use the WITH like you do: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html

Here is a functoinnal version of your code. But I am not quite sure of what you want :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fn_insert_test(json_data jsonb)
 returns  table(col_1 varchar(255),
                col_2 varchar(255),
                col_3 timestamp)
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
declare
    --json_data jsonb := '{"_data": [{"val1":"1", "val2":"1"}, {"val1":"2", "val2":"2"}]}';
begin
    create temp table res (col_1 varchar (255), col_2 varchar (255), col_3 timestamp) on commit drop;

    with my_table1(my_json) as
    (
        values(
        json_data 
        )
    )
    , inserted as
    (
        insert into test(col_1, col_2, col_3)
            select
                elem->>'val1', elem->>'val2', now()
            from
                my_table1 t
                , jsonb_array_elements(json_data->'_data') elem
        on conflict do nothing
        returning *
    )
    insert into res
    select *
    from inserted;

    --raise notice '%', res_v;

    return query select * from res;
end
$$
;


select fn_insert_test('{"_data": [{"val1":"1", "val2":"1"}, {"val1":"2", "val2":"2"}]}');
```

Comment: Thanks for advice. What i want to do is inserting data into "test(col_1, col_2, col_3)" table and getting the inserted records(rows). The function only returns inserted rows(duplicated rows are not included). The problem is that the column "col_1" is primary key so it cannot be duplicated. I used "on conflict" to check the duplicate. It seems that the error occurs because it doesn't know col_1 column in the test table.

Comment: Could you, please, add some data samples ? (in and out)

Comment: I added some pictures for test table.

Comment: With the test table(pictures added in the post), if I insert {"_data": [{"val1":"1", "val2":"1"}, {"val1":"2", "val2":"2"}]} via this function, the result row count has to be zero. If I insert {"_data": [{"val1":"10", "val2":"1"}, {"val1":"11", "val2":"2"}]}, row count is going to be 1 and the returning result has only one record: (col_1=11, col_2=2, col_3=2019-09-06 21:41(current time)).

Comment: Thank you! it works well. Is it okay to omit conflict column?? what if conflict conditions are multiple??

Comment: I am not quite sure but I think if there is multiple conflict they are all considered one. But it worths testing it ;) But I have no time left today ;)